# Como remover, inserir ou alterar um único caractere em um campo no MySql?

Tags: mysql, query, substring

Tenho a seguinte tabela no MySql:

```
Id   | comida     | preco
1    | batata     | 325
2    | carne      | 3.10
3    | speculoos  | 3.00
```

Queria poder alterar os pontos de acordo com as necessidades abaixo:

Caso o *comida = batata*, inserir um ponto depois do primeiro caractere.

Caso *comida = carne*, excluir o ponto depois do primeiro caractere e inseri-lo depois do segundo.

E o ultimo caso *comida = speculoos*, retirar o ponto depois do primeiro caractere.

Como devo montar essas *queries*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já é complicado tratar valor com decimais, ainda mais convertendo para `STRING` e alterar caractere.

O ideal seria usar cálculos, **definir fórmulas**, e não uma gambiarra.

Diante disso, então melhor multiplicar e/ou dividir.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN comida = 'batata' THEN preco * 0.01 ELSE
(CASE WHEN comida = 'carne' THEN preco * 10 ELSE
(CASE WHEN comida = 'speculoos' THEN preco * 100 ELSE preco 
END) END) END) PRECO
FROM tabela
```

A query funcionará da seguinte forma: **tentará as 3 condições, e se nenhuma atender, retorna o `preco` normal**.

---

#### Edit:

> Sim, basicamente isso, eu entendi a logica acima para numero, mas e se
>   no caso fossem palavras, como eu faria isso? – Shinchila_Matadora

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN comida = 'batata' THEN CAST(preco as DECIMAL(10,2)) * 0.01 ELSE
(CASE WHEN comida = 'carne' THEN CAST(preco as DECIMAL(10,2)) * 10 ELSE
(CASE WHEN comida = 'speculoos' THEN CAST(preco as DECIMAL(10,2)) * 100 ELSE CAST(preco as DECIMAL(10,2)) 
END) END) END) PRECO
FROM tabela
```

Comment: mas e se por acaso os valores que precisam ser alterados sejam palavras e não numeros?

Comment: Você está dizendo que seu campo `preco` é texto? É isso?

Comment: Sim, basicamente isso, eu entendi a logica acima para numero, mas e se no caso fossem palavras, como eu faria isso?

Comment: @Shinchila_Matadora adicionei na resposta. Veja se funciona